# MS Access Restricting table/form access

Tags: ms-access

Is there a simple way to allow users to only edit form entries they create and only allow an administrator to edit the table/all forms?  Ex: I need my entire staff to be able to add and edit their own meetings while not having the ability to edit other staff's meetings.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't *exactly* simple...  Access used to have all sorts of security built-in (and still does) but this has now been deprecated, so if your users want to, and know how, they can bypass your forms.  Access really isn't a secure platform, so any security you try to build in will only prevent inadvertent errors, but not even a half-hearted attack.

Anyway, you need to capture each user's user ID (Access can't do this out-of-the-box; this function will do it):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetUserA" (lpName As Any, ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long

Public Function WSUserName() As String         'Returns the workstation user name
    Dim Ret As Long, cbusername As Long, UserName As String
    UserName = Space(256)
    cbusername = Len(UserName)
    Ret = WNetGetUser(ByVal 0&, UserName, cbusername)
    If Ret = 0 Then
        UserName = Left(UserName, InStr(UserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        UserName = ""
    End If
    WSUserName = UserName
End Function
```

Then you need to use this as the default value of a `Creating_User` text field in your table/form.

You need to have a `tbl_Users` table, with, at minimum, a `UserID` field that contains the `WSUserName()` of the user and an `IsAdministrator` Yes/No field.

Then, in your form, in the `Form_Current` event handler, you need:

```
Me.AllowEdits = DLookup("IsAdministrator", "tbl_Users", "UserID = " & WSUserName()) Or Me.Creating_User = WSUserName()
Me.AllowDeletions = DLookup("IsAdministrator", "tbl_Users", "UserID = " & WSUserName()) Or Me.Creating_User = WSUserName()
```

This will prevent users from editing/deleting other people's records, while allowing administrators to edit/delete anyone's records.  Anyone can add records, and as the `Creating_User` field defaults to `WSUserName()` and should be read-only, only they (or an administrator) will be able to do anything with them.

The only problem with this method is that it presupposes that your PCs don't have shared logons.  If the PC is logged on in the morning and anyone can just walk up and start using it, you are going to have to use a different approach, but this method will work fine for PCs where users log in with their own ID, do their work, then log off, and then someone else can log in.